# Lindelöf and sequentially compact imply compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to show that every space $X$ that is Lindelöf and sequentially compact is also compact. Here is my attempt at a proof:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover for $X$. Since $X$ is Lindelöf, we can find a countable subcover $\{ A_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ of $X$. We assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists no finite subcover of $X$ contained in $\mathcal{A}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, choose an arbitrary point $x_n \in X - \bigcup_{m = 1}^n A_m$ (since $\{ A_1, ..., A_n \} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ is finite, by hypothesis it must not cover $X$, so that $X - \bigcup_{m = 1}^n A_m$ is non-empty). Since $X$ is sequentially compact, the sequence $(x_n)$ must have a convergent subsequence, say, $(x_{n_k}) \to x_0$. Since $\{ A_n \}$ cover $X$, there must exist some $n_{x_0} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $A_{n_{x_0}}$ contains $x_0$. This means that there exists some $K \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x_{n_k} \in A_{n_{x_0}}$ for all $k > K$. Consider any $k' > K$ such that $n_{k'} > n_{x_0}$. Since $k' > K$, then $x_{n_{k'}} \in A_{n_{x_0}}$ by the convergent subsequence condition. Since $n_{k'} > n_{x_0}$, then $A_{n_{x_0}} \subseteq \bigcup_{m = 1}^{n_{k'}} A_m$, so $x_{n_{k'}} \in X - \bigcup_{m = 1}^{n_{k'}} A_m$ implies that $x_{n_{k'}} \notin A_{n_{x_0}}$, a contradiction. Therefore, $X$ must be compact.

Is the argument sound?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your argument is sound.

I'd adjust as follows for readability. The sequence $x_n$ has a subsequence covering to some point $x$. Then $x\in A_N$ for some $N\in\mathbb Z^+$. But choose $x_M$ in the subsequence converging to $x$ with $M>N$. Then $A_N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ missing $x_M$. This is a contradiction; therefore, $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

*Comment:* We can instead prove $(*)$ Sequentially compact $\Longrightarrow$ Countably compact.
Then note:

Lindelof = every open over has a coutable subcover

Countably compact = every countble open cover has a finite subcover

so we deduce

Lindelof & Countably compact $\Longleftrightarrow$ Compact.  [a.k.a. "bicompact"]
And then $(*)$ gives us what is required.

The idea would be that using $(*)$ as a lemma is clearer than doing both parts at once.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.